# Get current Location in onInfoWindowClick

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use the current Location of the user in `onInfoWindowClick`. I get the position in `onLocationChangend` but the app crashed when I click on the info window and I'm not sure about reffering to the current location the right way in `onInfoWindowClick`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady (GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
    setUpMap();
}

private void setUpMap() {
/*....*/
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new UserInfoWindowAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            LatLng markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
            Location myLocation;

            myLocation.setLatitude(myposition.latitude);
            myLocation.setLongitude(myposition.longitude);

            Location markerLoc = new Location("marker");
            markerLoc.setLatitude(markerPosition.latitude);
            markerLoc.setLongitude(markerPosition.longitude);

            float meters = myLocation.distanceTo(markerLoc);

            if (meters < 200) {
                /*...*/
            } else {
                /*...*/
            }
        }
    });
}

 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    myposition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myposition).zoom(14).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.Location.setLatitude(double)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: myLocation ? try : myLocation = new Location(); , then set latitude and longitude for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that you've got a null Location object because you never initialize it.  However, since `onLocationChanged()` gives you a Location reference, there's no need to convert to LatLng and then back to a Location.
So, just use a member variable that is a Location:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

        Location mLocation;
        //...............
```

Then just set your Location member variable in `onLocationChanged()`.
Also, if you want to get more than one Location update to track the user's movement, remove the call to unregister for location updates.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    //myposition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //add this:
    mLocation = location;

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myposition).zoom(14).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Then the InfoWindowClickListener is simplified, just make sure that `mLocation` is not null before you use it:

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new UserInfoWindowAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            //null check, do nothing if current location is not known:
            if (mLocation == null) return;

            LatLng markerPosition = marker.getPosition();

            Location markerLoc = new Location("marker");
            markerLoc.setLatitude(markerPosition.latitude);
            markerLoc.setLongitude(markerPosition.longitude);

            float meters = mLocation.distanceTo(markerLoc);

            if (meters < 200) {
                /*...*/
            } else {
                /*...*/
            }
        }
    });
}
```